# Image decrypted look like the encrypted one using AES

Tags: matlab, encryption, aes

my AES algorithm work nice for a text but when I tried to adapt it to image it still not working. all seems to be logical to me and cannot find where is the troubles. thanks 
this is the main program , I split the matrix into 4x4 sub matrix then i use aesencrypt/aesdecrypt function (this too functions work good for a text)

```
  function [encrypt] = aes(s, oper, mode, I, iv, sbit)switch lower(oper)
        case {'encrypt', 'enc', 'e'}
            oper = 0;
        case {'decrypt', 'dec', 'd'}
            oper = 1;
        otherwise
            error('Bad ''oper'' parameter.');
    end

    E.sub_mat=[];
    E.final=[];
    [m n]=size(I);
    p=m/4*n/4;
    k=1;
    %Splite the image matrix into 4*4 sub matrix
    for j=1:4:m
        for i=1:4:n
            E.sub_mat{k}=imcrop(I,[i,j,3,3]);
            k=k+1;
        end
    end

    input =zeros(4,4,'double');
    blocks=p;
    l=1;
    for l=1:blocks
    input = E.sub_mat{l};
    switch lower(mode)

        case {'ecb'}
            % Electronic Codebook Mode
            % ------------------------
            output = zeros(4,4,'double');

                if (oper)
                    % decrypt
                    output = aesdecrypt(s,input);
                else
                    % encrypt
                    output = aesencrypt(s,input);
                end    

            % Dites ceci est la matrice donnée:



        case {'cbc'}
            % Cipher Block Chaining Mode
            % --------------------------
            if (nargin < 5)
                error('Missing initialization vector ''iv''.');
            end
            output = zeros(4,4,'double');
            ob = iv;

                if (oper)
                    % decrypt
                    in = input;
                    output = bitxor(ob(:), aesdecrypt(s,in)');
                    ob = in;
                else
                    % encrypt
                    ob = bitxor(ob(:), input(idx));
                    ob = aesencrypt(s, ob);
                    output = ob;
                end


            % store iv for block passing
            s.iv = ob;


        case {'cfb'}
            % Cipher Feedback Mode
            % --------------------
            % Special mode with bit manipulations
            % sbit = 1..128
            if (nargin < 6)
                error('Missing ''sbit'' parameter.');
            end
            % get number of bits
            input=input(:);
            bitlen = 8*length(input);
            % loop counter
            rounds = round(bitlen/sbit);
            % check 
            if (rem(bitlen, sbit))
                error('Message length in bits is not multiple of ''sbit''.');
            end
            % convert input to bitstream
            inputb = reshape(de2bi(input,8,2,'left-msb')',1,bitlen);
            % preset init. vector
            ib = iv;
            ibb = reshape(de2bi(ib,8,2,'left-msb')',1,128);
            % preset output binary stream
            outputb = zeros(size(inputb));
            for i = 1:rounds
                iba = aesencrypt(s, ib);
                % convert to bit, MSB first
                ibab = reshape(de2bi(iba,8,2,'left-msb')',1,128);
                % strip only sbit MSB bits
                % this goes to xor
                ibab = ibab(1:sbit);
                % strip bits from input
                inpb = inputb((i - 1)*sbit + (1:sbit));
                % make xor
                outb = bitxor(ibab, inpb);
                % write to output
                outputb((i - 1)*sbit + (1:sbit)) = outb;
                if (oper)
                    % decrypt
                    % prepare new iv - bit shift
                    ibb = [ibb((1 + sbit):end) inpb];
                else
                    % encrypt
                    % prepare new iv - bit shift
                    ibb = [ibb((1 + sbit):end) outb];
                end
                % back to byte ary
                ib = bi2de(vec2mat(ibb,8),'left-msb');
                % loop
            end
            output = bi2de(vec2mat(outputb,8),'left-msb');
            % store iv for block passing
            s.iv = ib;
            output=reshape(output,4,4);

        case {'ofb'}
            % Output Feedback Mode
            % --------------------
            if (nargin < 5)
                error('Missing initialization vector ''iv''.');
            end
            output = zeros(4,4,'double');
            ib = iv;

                % encrypt, decrypt
                ib = aesencrypt(s, ib);
                output = bitxor(ib(:), input);

            % store iv for block passing
            s.iv = ib;

        case {'ctr'}
            % Counter Mode
            % ------------
            if (nargin < 5)
                iv = 1;
            end
            input=input(:);
            output = zeros(1,length(input));
            idx = 1:16;
            for i = (iv):(iv + blocks - 1)
                ib = AES_GET_COUNTER(i);
                ib = aesencrypt(s, ib);
                output(idx) = bitxor(ib(:), input(idx));
                idx = idx + 16;
            end
            s.iv = iv + blocks;
            output=reshape(output,4,4);
        otherwise
            error('Bad ''oper'' parameter.');
    end
    E.final{l}=output;
    end
    encrypt=zeros(m,n,'double');
    a=1;
    for i=1:(m/4)
        for j=1:(n/4)
            r2=4*i;r1=r2-3;
            c2=4*j;c1=c2-3;    
            encrypt(r1:r2,c1:c2)=E.final{a}; 
            a=a+1;
        end
    end
```

aesencrypt function

function [out] = aesencrypt(s, in)
    state = in;

```
% Initial round
% AddRoundKey keyexp(1:4)
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(1:4, :))');

% Loop over (s.rounds - 1) rounds
for i = 1:(s.rounds - 1)
    % SubBytes - lookup table
    state = s.s_box(state + 1);
    % ShiftRows
    state = shift_rows(state, 0);
    % MixColumns
    state = mix_columns(state, s);
    % AddRoundKey keyexp(i*4 + (1:4))
    state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp((1:4) + 4*i, :))');
end

% Final round
% SubBytes - lookup table
state = s.s_box(state + 1);
% ShiftRows
state = shift_rows(state, 0);
% AddRoundKey keyexp(4*s.rounds + (1:4))
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(4*s.rounds + (1:4), :))');
out = state;
```

aesdecrypt function

```
function [out] = aesdecrypt(s, in)state = in;

% Initial round
% AddRoundKey keyexp(s.rounds*4 + (1:4))
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(s.rounds*4 + (1:4), :))');

% Loop over (s.rounds - 1) rounds
for i = (s.rounds - 1):-1:1
    % ShiftRows
    state = shift_rows(state, 1);
    % SubBytes - lookup table
    state = s.inv_s_box(state + 1);
    % AddRoundKey keyexp(i*4 + (1:4))
    state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp((1:4) + 4*i, :))');
    % MixColumns
    state = mix_columns(state, s);
end

% Final round
% ShiftRows
state = shift_rows(state, 1);
% SubBytes - lookup table
state = s.inv_s_box(state + 1);
% AddRoundKey keyexp(1:4)
state = bitxor(state, (s.keyexp(1:4, :))');
out = state;
```

TEST FILE

```
[file path]=uigetfile('*.*','Select the Input Image');
Img=imread([path file]);
keyh= {'2b' '7e' '15' '16' '28' 'ae' 'd2' 'a6'...
    'ab' 'f7' '15' '88' '09' 'cf' '4f' '3c'};
key = hex2dec(keyh);

s = aesinit(key);
[n m h]=size(Img);
R=Img(:,:,1);
G = Img(:,:,2);
B = Img(:,:,3);
R=double(R);
G=double(G);
B=double(B);
x=length(R);

ivh = {'00' '01' '02' '03' '04' '05' '06' '07'...
    '08' '09' '0a' '0b' '0c' '0d' '0e' '0f'};
iv = hex2dec(ivh);

s = aesinit(key);
mode= input('entrer le choix:')
switch lower(mode)
    case {'decrypt', 'dec', 'd'}


mode = input('entrer le mode:')
switch lower(mode)
    case {'ecb'}

image_decrypt_R = aes(s, 'dec', 'ecb', R);
image_decrypt_G = aes(s, 'dec', 'ecb', G);
image_decrypt_B = aes(s, 'dec', 'ecb', B);
    case {'cbc'}

image_decrypt_R = aes(s, 'dec', 'cbc', R, iv);
image_decrypt_G = aes(s, 'dec', 'cbc', G , iv);
image_decrypt_B = aes(s, 'dec', 'cbc', B , iv);
    case {'cfb'}
sbit= input('entrer 0<sbit<128 ')

image_decrypt_R = aes(s, 'dec', 'cfb', R, iv, sbit);
image_decrypt_G = aes(s, 'dec', 'cfb', G, iv, sbit);
image_decrypt_B = aes(s, 'dec', 'cfb', B, iv, sbit);  
    case {'ofb'}

image_decrypt_R = aes(s, 'dec', 'ofb', R , iv);
image_decrypt_G = aes(s, 'dec', 'ofb', G , iv);
image_decrypt_B = aes(s, 'dec', 'ofb', B , iv);
    otherwise
        error( 'bad''oper''parameter.');

end

image_decrypt = cat(3,image_decrypt_R, image_decrypt_G, image_decrypt_B);


Image = image_decrypt;

imwrite(Image, 'image_decryptée.jpg');


    case {'encrypt', 'enc', 'e'}


mode = input('entrer le mode:')

switch lower(mode)

    case {'ecb'}

image_crypt_R = aes(s, 'enc', 'ecb', R);
image_crypt_G = aes(s, 'enc', 'ecb', G);
image_crypt_B = aes(s, 'enc', 'ecb', B);
    case {'cbc'}

image_crypt_R = aes(s, 'enc', 'cbc', R, iv);
image_crypt_G = aes(s, 'enc', 'cbc', G , iv);
image_crypt_B = aes(s, 'enc', 'cbc', B , iv);
    case {'cfb'}
sbit= input('entrer 0<sbit<128 ')

image_crypt_R = aes(s, 'enc', 'cfb', R, iv, sbit);
image_crypt_G = aes(s, 'enc', 'cfb', G, iv, sbit);
image_crypt_B = aes(s, 'enc', 'cfb', B, iv, sbit);  
    case {'ofb'}

image_crypt_R = aes(s, 'enc', 'ofb', R , iv);
image_crypt_G = aes(s, 'enc', 'ofb', G , iv);
image_crypt_B = aes(s, 'enc', 'ofb', B , iv);
    otherwise
        error( 'bad''oper''parameter.');

end

        image_crypt = cat(3,image_crypt_R, image_crypt_G, image_crypt_B);


Image = image_crypt;



imwrite(Image, 'image_cryptée.jpg');

    otherwise
        error('Bad ''oper'' parameter.');
end
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? I think it might be something like this, in which case it would be good to know what goes in the bits I've left blank. "I've written some code to encrypt and decrypt using AES. When I apply it to text, it encrypts and decrypts correctly; I have checked this by _________. But when I apply it to image data, after decryption I still have random nonsense rather than a valid image file; an example that should have worked is __________ and I know it should have worked because ___________."

Comment: Er, actually, that still isn't a question. The question would then be something like "What have I done wrong, and how is it possible that my code works correctly for text but incorrectly for images?".

Comment: My guess at the most likely answer, if it's really true that it works correctly on text but breaks on images, is that you are processing some file in text mode rather than binary mode, and it's therefore being subjected to some kind of line-ending conversion which corrupts binary data. But to verify or refute that guess we'd need to see your code that actually applies this encryption/decryption to text and images -- which you haven't included in your question. (You should include it.)

Comment: Ok sir @GarethMcCaughan i will copy all the code, and my question i why i still have an encrypted image after using decryption !!

Comment: What do you mean by "an encrypted image"? Do you mean (1) that it's exactly the same as before you tried to decrypt it, or (2) that for some other reason you can tell that it's the result of encrypting a valid image, or (3) just that it looks like random junk as if it were the result of encryption?

Comment: this is it the code mr @GarethMcCaughan and the encrypted image it looks like random, a result of an encryption !!

Comment: Not a solution but a workround.  Convert the binary image to a text file in Base64.  Encrypt/decrypt the text file.  Convert the Base64 back into a binary image.  That might buy you some time to work out what the real problem is and solve it in version 2..

Comment: do u have any code for that @rossum

Comment: Joe: No, sorry.  I don't use matlab.  Look up Base64 in the matlab documentation or user sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing your encrypted image to a JPEG file. JPEG is a lossy compressed format, and the resulting file will *not* have the exact same pixel values as were in the image.

The differences are typically small and unobtrusive to the human eye. But it is in the nature of encryption that a tiny difference in ciphertext may mean a complete scrambling of the plaintext.

So, you take your image; you encrypt its pixel values using AES (OK so far); you write it out to a JPEG image; you read it back in -- and now the pixel values have *changed*. You decrypt its pixel values using AES, and you get nonsense -- because the ciphertext you are decrypting is not the result of an AES encryption, it's the result of an AES encryption *plus* the errors introduced by JPEG compression.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the solution? @Gareth

Comment: If you have an "image" and need all its pixel values to be recorded exactly, save it in a lossless format like PNG. Note that the encrypted image file will be substantially larger than the original one, because random-looking pixel values will not be well compressible (losslessly *or* lossily). Or: store your encrypted image data in some other form rather than as an image.

Comment: For instance, if the original image comes from an image file, just encrypt the bytes of that file. No need for the encryption process to think of it as an image at all.

Comment: it means to use imencode and imdecode functions? @Gareth McCaughan

Comment: I was thinking of the situation where your image starts off in a file. Then never mind the fact that it happens to have an image in it; just treat it as a sequence of bytes and encrypt it as such, and save it in a new file. Reverse the process for decryption. If you start off with an image in a MATLAB array, then by all means do something like you've done here. (But if you then save it to a file, make it a PNG rather than a JPEG.)

Comment: its seems to work sir @Gareth . First  I encrypt the file data then its copied in file text. I get the original image after decryption. I still have one problem is how to get an image png after padding.. how can I do that ? I tried but I got the error :Attempt to reference field of
non-structure array.

Error in EncryptFile (line 60)
h = jImg.getHeight;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it sounds as if the thing called jImg is an ordinary MATLAB array (containing pixel values, perhaps) and whatever it's been handed to was expecting it to be something fancier (something containing image-specific data somehow, I guess). Perhaps make that a new question on SO?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gareth